# Открыть консоль и автоматически выполнять команды

Tags: c, cmd

Как открывать консоль (командная строка, cmd) и выполнять там команды автоматический? Чтобы за меня вводились. Командную строку я открываю так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {

system("cmd.exe");


getch();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: А кто их "за вас" вводить должен? Вы их, конечно, можете прямо в программе указать, но это же все равно вы делаете...

Comment: @Harry Извиняюсь, неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Как эти команды, которые должны выполниться автоматически, добавить в программу? Что почитать, куда смотреть?

Answer (score 3):

Команды записываются в `system()`.

Хотите вывести `dir`?

```
system("dir");
```

Хотите скопировать файл?

```
system("copy src.txt dest.txt");
```

И так далее. Хотите сразу пачку команд? Пишите их в пакетный файл (.cmd или .bat) и вызывайте его...